# SQL: How can I retrieve how many helpful answers a user has posted, using Stack Exchange Data Explorer?

Tags: sql, t-sql, dataexplorer

I am trying to construct a SQL query for [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/) that given a particular Stack Overflow user, will list their number of accepted answers, number of answers with score > 0, and number of answers that have either been accepted AND/OR have score > 0.

Here is the query I have so far, which only counts up accepted answers:

```
DECLARE @UserId int = ##UserId##

SELECT 
    Count(a.Id) AS Accepted
FROM
    Posts q
  INNER JOIN
    Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE
    a.OwnerUserId = @UserId
  AND
    a.PostTypeId = 2
```

When you run it on my user id (2234742), it shows the following output:

```
Accepted
70
```

I am looking for output like the following:

```
Accepted     Score > 0    Accepted or Score > 0
X            X            X
```

To edit my existing query, you can go to [my existing data.stackexchange.com query page](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/344344/how-many-helpful-answers-have-i-posted) and click "fork query" underneath the query body. The schema will be shown on the right. I am new to SQL, so thank you for the help!

N.B. Remember that `Accepted or Score > 0` is not just the sum of the other two columns, because there is overlap!

Comment: Not that familiar with how the data is stored in SEDE, but something like [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/344359/how-many-helpful-answers-have-i-posted) should give you a decent start.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Thanks, that is helpful - I'll play around with that and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
a.id,
sum(case when a.PostTypeId = 2 then 1 end) AS Accepted,
sum(case when a.PostTypeId = someval then 1 end) AS 'score>0',
sum(case when a.PostTypeId = someval then 1 end) AS 'acceptedorscore>0'
FROM Posts q INNER JOIN
Posts a ON q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id
WHERE a.OwnerUserId = @UserId
group by a.id, a.PostTypeId
```

Replace 'someval' with the posttype to get what you need. You need to group by posttype

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't look like it's summing properly: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/344358/how-many-helpful-answers-have-i-posted

Comment: you need to include conditions for score > 0 and accepted and score > 0.

Comment: if you tell the conditions, i can include them

Comment: Thanks, I very much appreciate the help. For accepted answers, `q.AcceptedAnswerId = a.Id` where q is the question that the answer was posted to. For score > 0, I think there might need to be an inner join with votes, like in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/7330/users-with-many-upvoted-posts-but-low-average-score).